# Control characters in Python shell

Tags: python, shell, readline

I have a problem when I am using Python interactive shell.

I love emacs-style key bindings, but when I typed `<ctrl> A` or `<ctrl> K`, it echo `^A` or `^K`. Like:

```
:)[12:16]root:~ # python
Python 2.7.9 (default, May 15 2015, 01:13:44)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print ^A^K^H
```

Is it due to *readline* lib? I have updated readline, but it seems no help.

Comment: try this print chr(1)

Comment: @Ajay, nothing printed by `print chr(1)`

Comment: what do you want to achieve by printing ctrl-A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the readline development package and rebuild and reinstall Python.